# Tomcat Background Thread Starting twice?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a question to Tomcat context listeners. 
What i am trying to do:
Starting ONE thread when tomcat starts wich will basicly do some backround DB operations.
I have implemented a ContextLstener Class, set it up in the web.xml and implemented a simple Thread-Class.

My Problem is, that Tomcat starts this thread twice or sometimes even 3 times and i dont understand why.
Yes im kinda new to Tomcat and Servlets and yes i have search stackoverflow for a soloution but couldnt find anything.

heres my code:
ServletContextListener:

```
public class EventToUserServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private DatabaseContextThread thread = null;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        if ((thread == null) || (!thread.isAlive())) {
            System.out.println("STARTING CONTEXT THREAD");
            this.thread = new DatabaseContextThread();
            this.thread.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        try {
            System.out.println("STOPING CONTEXT THREAD");
            thread.doShutdown();
            thread.interrupt();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error Stoping Thread: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Thread Class

```
public class DatabaseContextThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                //TODO Implement Context
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = new Date();

                System.out.println(date + " THIS IS THREAD!!! " + this.toString());
                sleep(20000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DatabaseContextThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }

    public void doShutdown() {

    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTfull Server Thesis</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>de.mk</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>10</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>de.mk.dao.listener.EventToUserServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTfull Server Thesis</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Sat Apr 12 11:26:27 CEST 2014 THIS IS THREAD!!! Thread[Thread-6,5,main]

Sat Apr 12 11:26:29 CEST 2014 THIS IS THREAD!!! Thread[Thread-8,5,main]

Sat Apr 12 11:26:47 CEST 2014 THIS IS THREAD!!! Thread[Thread-6,5,main]

Sat Apr 12 11:26:49 CEST 2014 THIS IS THREAD!!! Thread[Thread-8,5,main]

Comment: This looks fine - are you sure you are not deploying the application multiple times? Also, **don't use `Thread`**, use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). You can schedule a task to happen at start and then cancel it. Using raw `Thread` is a very bad idea unless you know exactly what you are doing. Read [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/scheduledexecutorservice.html).

Comment: Yes im sure im not starting the thread multiple times. Anyway I followed ur advice and implemented this funcionality using contextlistener and scheduledExecutorService wich is working fine for now. The behavoir of it is still the same tho, it starts the service thred 2 times when lauchning tomcat the only difference is that it manages to close the first thread this time (wich was not the case using the raw Thread), so i have only one running background process. Kinda strange and i stil dont get why but i found a workarround for it at least. Thx for pointing me in the right direction ;>

Comment: Old but potentially useful: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40811

Answer (score 0):

Check how many times have you defined the context. The context listener will be executed for each context.
You can have multiple context if you use virtual host, or if you define one context in the war (META-INF/context.xml) and other in server.xml (you should not define contect here).